# Should we use code-blocks (not for code)

Tags: discussion, formatting

I'm wondering if it makes more sense to use code blocks in an answer to make it easier to read and help separate from the instruction to the reasoning etc.

As in

"This can be solved using method XYZ

Go to `Sample` > `Word` > `3`

And then do process ABC"

---

The reason I'm asking, is because somebody mentioned to only use code-blocks for `code`.

So, I started doing this:

> This can be solved using method XYZ
>
> Go to *Sample* > *Word* > *3*
>
> And then do process ABC

(because without any variation it makes it more difficult to diffrentiate)

> This can be solved using method XYZ
>
> Go to Sample > Word > 3
>
> And then do process ABC

---

However, I notice many people (myself included, up until recently) would use it for better formatting (It definitely makes it easier to read - I'm not sure if that's problematic, since it isn't actually *code*)

---

I'm looking for any input and opinions on this.

Comment: Aren't those quote blocks, not `code blocks`?

Comment: @seaturtle yes, I've placed in quote blocks, but I'm referring to the `code blocks`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. I've done it myself but after frequenting another SE community learned that is has negative effects and is frowned upon.

[Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right)

https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7437/using-code-ticks-for-technical-term-highlighting-considered-harmful

> [Using backticks is] not just distracting, it's semantically wrong. Code formatting is semantic HTML to indicate to a parser that text is code. If we start lying to our parsers, we break tools built on HTML. Consider screen readers: if a visually impaired user configures their software to spell out code tags, or to have an easy keyboard shortcut with a macro called "jump to next code span/block and highlight" for easy copy-pasting, we are significantly disabling their ability to interact with the page. Further disabling, I should say.